SameSite issue with Quarkus and with Keycloak
When I am on the keycloak page:
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 6
Cookie “KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite auth

Cookie “KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite auth

Cookie “KEYCLOAK_SESSION” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite auth

Cookie “KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite auth

Cookie “AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite auth

Cookie “KC_RESTART” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite auth

When I am redirected to Quarkus:
Some cookies are misusing the recommended “SameSite“ attribute 2

Cookie “q_auth_d97c331f-595d-4592-8b1a-6166bbeea031” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite localhost:8442

Cookie “q_session_chunk_2” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite localhost:8442

This error page has no error code in its security info
In Keycloak Web origins is set to * and + and also the url.
Everything is done in localhost.
I also set the cors setting to false in Quarkus. Also added all the localhost's and the right ports.
I am out of ideas.

Quarkus OIDC has a property to set SameSite for the session cookie, quarkus.oidc.authentication.cookie-same-site, and while no similar property for the state cookie exists yet, one can set it easily with https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#same-site-cookie. However, looks like the real issue is to do with the session cookie being split to chunks when its size is 4K+. And there was a bug related to it. Please try 3.10.0 or disable the automatic session cookie split with quarkus.oidc.token-state-manager.split-tokens=true and you should get you login to Quarkus working.
